# integrate UISearchController with Async result update in swift

Tags: json, swift, uisearchcontroller, swifty-json

I want to implement UISearchContoller that search from webservice JSON with swifty json, exactly like apple's appStore when you search for an app, it loads without load them into tableView

here is what I have done in updateSearchResultsForSearchController method:

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!)
}


func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String) {
filteredContents = myStruct.filter{$0.name.rangeOfString(searchText) != nil

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting more of your code would be nice, like what you are using to get the results from the web service, However, I will try to step you through it anyway.

I have done with before just using a UISearchBar and it's delegate method, one the user pressed the search button or enter, I would use NSURLSession to pass the user's search terms to the API, and parsed the response.

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    let searchText : String = searchBar.text
    webService.getRecipe(ingredient: searchText, completionHandler: { (recipeArray) in
            self.highProteinArray = recipeArray
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            })
        })
}
```

As you can see I used a callback to handle setting the newly parsed data to a variable for later use, and then reloaded the collectionView.  This way your tableView/collectionView will load and set itself up while you are waiting for the response from the web service and then parsing it, once that is complete you just reload to show the new data.

To add a little extra you could even add a fading in animation in your cellForItemAtIndexPath or cellForRowAtIndexPath, whichever you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @jacob, what I have ended up doing is that I have called my async method which connect to the web service to receive JSON result in updateSearchResult so every time a new character inserted in searchBar api calls and receive new results